# How can i make a page refresh in a certain time all days?

Tags: javascript

I want my page to auto-refresh everyday at 00:01.

I've this

```js
var targetTime = new Date();
var now = targetTime.getTime();
targetTime.setHours(0, 17, 0, 0); // hour, minute, second, millisecond
var time = targetTime.getTime() - now;
window.setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.reload(true);
}, time);
```

The problem is when it's 00:01 the website always is re-freshing.

Comment: Well, then -1 second to the counter for seconds. But you also have to remember the page loads Javascript after the page has been loaded, then starts the timer. So wait until the page is loaded to start this.

Comment: Before setting up the setTimeout compare the current time with the target time and if it is less than a minute set up the timeout for the target time + 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably more efficient to check what the hour and minute of the day is once a minute, like so:

```
setInterval(() => {
  const date = new Date()
  const hour = date.getHours()
  const minute = date.getMinutes()
  if (hour === 0 && minute === 1) window.location.reload()
}, 60000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok! So i've manage to do this, and it works!

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds)
{
    var now = new Date(), then = new Date();
    then.setHours(hours,minutes,seconds,0);
    if(then.getTime()<now.getTime())
    {
        then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }

    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
}
```

with

```
refreshAt(0,1,0);
```